# How do I get the below T-SQL to work in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to convert the below query to LINQ statement:

```
SELECT
    TOP 10
      S.Id
    , S.Url
    , S.Score
    , MAX(LastUpdated) AS LastUpdated
FROM
    Sites S
    LEFT JOIN History H ON S.ID = H.SiteId
WHERE
    S.Active = 1 AND Approved = 1
GROUP BY
      S.Id
    , S.Url
    , S.Score
ORDER BY LastUpdated
```

Please HELP!

Comment: That seems very straightforward.  I highly suggest looking at some tutorials online, also, this link has some nice samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var result = (
    from s in Sites
    join h in History
        on s.ID equals h.SiteID into left1
    from left2 in left1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where s.Active == true && left2.Approved == true
    group left2 by new {s.ID, s.Url, s.Score} into grouped
    orderby grouped.Max(h => h.LastUpdated)
    select new
    {
        SiteID = grouped.Key.ID,
        Url = grouped.Key.Url,
        Score = grouped.Key.Score,
        LastUpdated = grouped.Max(h => h.LastUpdated)
    })
    .Take(10);
```

It worked when I tested it in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), anyway.